# How to get features of another point layer when geomequals ? (Using Default Values in Attributes Form Qgis 3.2.1)

Tags: qgis, default-value

I have 2 different point layers with attributes fields as shown in the picture below. They both have a different amount of features. Now i want that all features of layer B gets filled with some feature attributes of layer A as long they are on the map at the same position. (I used the snapping function to be sure that some positons between the 2 Layers should be equal)

So was testing to use default values for each field in layer B and failed. For example:

Layer **B** Field **B1** - Default value: *Case when geomequals(A,A1) then 1 end*

The output I got here on all features of Layer B for fields B1 - B3 using that expression was always just NULL instead of 1. (The 1 was just for testing)

Anyone here got an solution for this issue and an additional expression for 1 which refers to the attribues in layer A for the fields A1, A2, A3 ?

[image]

Comment: Use `geomequals('targetlayername','targetfieldname')` with `'`. Or use `join by location`.

Comment: @MrXsquared
Thx. 
Join by location its not really usefull for this because the amount of features for each layer arent static. They change all the time.

Only using for default value in B1 **geomequals('A','A1')** work so far and it helps. (i get the attribut values A1 in B1) 

But I am still struggling with an extended expression for a defaul value of B1 like: 
case when geomequals('A' , 'A1') is true then 1 end. Here i still get always NULL. I would like to have an expression when Layer A is on same postion as layer B then add a specific value eg. '123' to B1 or B2 or B3.

Answer (score 1):

The geomequals function does not work that way. I also want to add that this function requires [refFunctions Plugin](https://github.com/enricofer/refFunctions).

From help:

```
Retrieve target field value when source feature is equal to target feature in target layer.

Syntax:
geomequals('targetLayer','targetField') 

Arguments:
 - targetLayer → the name of a currently loaded layer, for example
   'myLayer'.
 - targetField → a field in target layer we want as result when source
   feature is within target feature, for example 'myField'. If
   targetField is equal to '$geometry' The WKT geometry of targetFeature
   willbe retrieved  Number of feature tested is limited to 100000 to
   avoid time wasting loops

Example:
geomequals('targetLayer','TargetField') 
geomequals('targetLayer','$geometry')
```

What you can do with this function is something like

```
Case 
When 
geomequals('A','id') is not null then '123' 
else null  
end
```

It checks whether a point of layer B has an identical position as one of layer A has. It returns 123 if a point of A shares the same position AND this layer A point has an attribute value in field id (is not null).

Make sure to use `'`.

Use this in field calculator to update your points or add a rule for a default value like this:

[image]